# Where to install local software that runs before /usr is available?

Tags: debian, directory-structure, udev, initramfs

I'm writing a local program to be called by a udev `IMPORT{program}` rule. Normally, I'd install local software in `/usr/local`, but these udev rules are run when block devices appear. So they're running long before `/usr` is necessarily mounted.

I believe I'll also have to configure this to be copied to initramfs (which is easily done with `/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/`). Normally, it seems, things use the same path on initramfs as on the root filesystem. (edit: it appears I don't actually have to add it to initramfs, the events are re-triggered after rootfs is mounted)

`/etc` is version controlled, so binaries there are best avoided.

I'm thinking my best bet may just be to install this in `/lib/udev`, under a file name starting with `local-` to avoid clashing with any future files from the distro. The also makes the udev rules file prettier (since it won't need to specify full path).

This machine is running Debian Squeeze. Is there some standard location for this file? I don't believe [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) or [Debian Policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/) specifies one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would put these in `/lib/udev` if provided by a deb package and in `/etc` otherwise.

If you deploy the program on several machines, I recommend making a deb package; it will make deployment and version tracking easier. The [Debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian) has information, or you can read the [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/) (ignoring the non-technical bits). `dh` makes this a breeze (there's even a [`dh_installudev`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dh_installudev)).

If this is just for one machine, I'd put the binary in version control as well, or else check in the source and a makefile and ignore the binary. You may also want to put a symbolic link in `/lib/udev`. I don't recommend putting a non-packaged file in `/lib/udev` because you'll forget it's there.

Comment: Packaging it is indeed a good idea, though this is going on one system (maybe eventually two), so I'm not sure its worth it, especially as I'm not worried about forgetting its there, as this is a well-documented server build. Binaries in /etc is not only a pain with version control (and ignoring the executable even worse, as then the rollback you *thought* you did, you didn't really, and your backups aren't complete, etc.), its also actually explicitly against FHS. But, having said that, "package it" is the best answer so far, and I'll accept it tomorrow if nothing better is suggested.

Comment: @derobert The FHS constrains distributions, not administrators. I don't think I've ever needed a binary in `/etc`, but if I did, I'd create a `/etc/Makefile` with compilation instructions.

Comment: While the FHS is indeed a standard for distros, ISVs, etc., following it in local administration strikes me as a best practice, so I'm automatically hesitant to do something it explicitly says not to. Thinking more about it, I'm going to package it, even though its only going on one system. That preserves the expectation that /lib is only for stuff from the package manager. (We have our own apt repositories, so it'll be easy to install, upgrade, etc, too)

Answer (score 1):

`/lib/udev` looks rather reasonable. It will not interfere with anything not related to `udev`, so package management would not be much harmed. Other than this, you're left with a new subdirectory under `/opt/` (will need full path).

Comment: Well, `/opt` isn't necessarily on the root filesystem either. But yeah, so far I've just gone with putting it in `/lib/udev`.